# Adding a table stops js show/hide from working

Tags: javascript

I have a show/hide function on a web page where I want to improve the layout, but when I added a new table to put in headers for the data, the show/hide stopped working.

A snippet of the original code is:

```
<table id="cart-list">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
    <tr class="cl-group">
      <td class="cl-sh" title="Show [+] or Hide [-] this lists' products">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2">Cart List One:
        <table id="cl-chg-1" class="cl-other cl-chg">
          <tr>
            <td>List Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="group_name[1]" value="Cart List One" maxlength="255" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>List Comments:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="group_comments[1]" maxlength="255" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><button type="button" onclick="cancelGroupEdit();">Cancel</button></td>
            <td><button type="submit" name="change" value="1">Go</button></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </div>
  <tr>
    <td>Stuff Here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Stuff Here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the js used is

```
var groups = document.getElementsByClassName("cl-sh");
if (groups) {
  for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    groups[i].onclick = function() {
      this.classList.toggle('cl-a');
      var productsDisplay = '';
      if (this.classList.contains('cl-a')) {
        productsDisplay = 'none';
      }

      var nextRow = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
      while (nextRow) {
        if (nextRow.classList.contains('cl-group')) {
          break;
        }
        nextRow.style.display = productsDisplay;
        nextRow = nextRow.nextElementSibling;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A fiddle can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/65j1nvpq/1/

The broken function with the additional table code added can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/cmgqeLf7/

I don't really understand why having an additional table is breaking the function.

Any suggestions on a fix for this?

Comment: @Roy Nothing to do with the divs. Even with them completely removed it doesn't work. See https://jsfiddle.net/eg3ch6w7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your JS function do when you click on the +/- cell?

Firstly, it toggles whether the clicked cell contains the `cl-a` class. Then, it runs through all remaining rows in the same table, showing or hiding them as appropriate, until it finds a row with the class `cl-group`, or hits the end of the rows in that table.

Note the word *same* in the last paragraph.

In your first fiddle, you have one table.  In your second fiddle, you have two, and the rows you wish to toggle the display of are not in the same table as the toggle button.  This is why they are not showing/hiding when you click the toggle button.

I'm not sure exactly what your requirements for showing/hiding rows are, so I'm not going to propose a fix.  However, understanding what the problem is may help you to find a fix for yourself.

Comment: @LukeThanks for the explanation of the process it runs through. Essentially I want it to perform in the same way, except that it will be hiding the content of the second table instead.

Comment: @Steph3071: In that case, the easiest way is probably to put an `id` on the second table and replace the line `var nextRow = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;` with `var nextRow = document.getElementById("your-table-id-here").tBodies[0].rows[0];`.